# Change column variable string from "1" to "01"

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that is a charachter type. The variables are a mix of 1, 01, 2, 01, 3, 03, 4, 04 etc.

How would I select all without a leading '0' and format so they are all 01, 02, 03, 04 etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We need to first convert it to `numeric` and use `sprintf`

```
df1$col1 <- sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(df1$col1))
df1$col1
#[1] "01" "01" "02" "01" "03" "03" "04" "04"
```

If it is a `factor` column, first convert to `character` before heading to `numeric`

```
df1$col1 <- sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(as.character(df1$col1)))
```

---

If there are LETTERS included

```
df1$col1 <- c(1, '01', 2, '01', 3, 'A', 4, '04')
i1 <- grepl("^[0-9]$", df1$col1)
df1$col1[i1] <- paste0("0", df1$col1[i1])
df1$col1
#[1] "01" "01" "02" "01" "03" "A"  "04" "04"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, '01', 2, '01', 3, '03', 4, '04'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful and worked. However, I forgot to mention that the variables also contain some values that have strict character values such as "A', "B' and "C". As such, converting from Char to Num is not suitable as "A", "B" and "C" etc are converted to NA.

Comment: no need to convert to numeric imo, just `sprintf("%02s", df1$col1)` does the job perfectly (and also meets @JustinGleeson's requirement to include characters)

Comment: @JustinGleeson IMHO and with great respect, could you try please Jaap's recommendation

Comment: @Jaap IMHO and with great respect, your code gives me `sprintf("%02s", df1$col1)
#[1] " 1" "01" " 2" "01" " 3" " A" " 4" "04"`. (changed some elements to letters

Comment: Strange, it gives me `[1] "01" "01" "02" "01" "03" "0A" "04" "04"` back

Comment: @Jaap I am using R 3.4.0 patched version

Comment: that might be the reason, I'm using 3.3.3

Comment: @Jaap In the past, I've noticed platform differences in `sprintf` before, particularly with zero-padding and Windows.

Comment: @joran thx for the follow-up; I'm on macOS; I've tested it on my Windows VM and there it gives the same output as Akrun posted in his comment above

Answer (score 3):

```
 vec<-c("01","1","2","03","05","3","4","A","B","XX")
 >vec
```

[1] "01" "1"  "2"  "03" "05" "3"  "4"  "A"  "B"  "XX"

Then:

```
 ifelse(nchar(vec)!=2,paste0("0",vec),vec)
```

[1] "01" "01" "02" "03" "05" "03" "04" "0A" "0B" "XX"

## EDIT (check only numeric ones. Leave characters unchanged)

```
 ifelse((nchar(vec)!=2 &!is.na(as.numeric(vec))) ,paste0("0",vec),vec)
```

[1] "01" "01" "02" "03" "05" "03" "04" "A"  "B"  "XX"

Answer (score 3):

This regex solution inserts a 0 when `col1` is a digit:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
      col1 = c(1, '01', 2, '01', 3, '03', 4, '04','A','XX'),
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1$col1 <- gsub("(\\d)+", "0\\1", df1$col1)
df1$col1
# [1] "01" "01" "02" "01" "03" "03" "04" "04" "A"  "XX"
```