# Changing the form of a number to another form

Tags: r

In my data, I have a column named "age" that numbers under 10 is like 01,02...09. How can I change that to 1,2,...9.
Thank you in advance.

```
Age= c(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12)
```

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488300/change-column-variable-string-from-1-to-01) might help you with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
age_new <- sub("^0+", "", Age)        
age_new
```