# How can I remove leading zeros for two digits number (01, 02, etc.) from the middle of character string using R?

Tags: r, regex, leading-zero

For the following string vector `s`, I hope to remove leading zeros in each elements, which is reverse of the answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488300/change-column-variable-string-from-1-to-01):

```
s <- c('week 01st', 'weeks 02nd', 'year2022week01st', 'week 4th')
```

The expected result will like:

```
s <- c('week 1st', 'weeks 2nd', 'year2022week1st', 'week 4th')
```

I test the following code, it's not working out since the regex syntax is not complete:

```
s <- 'week 01st'
sub('^0+(?=[1-9])', '', s, perl=TRUE)
sub('^0+([1-9])', '\\1', s)
```

Out:

```
[1] "week 01st"
```

How could I do that using R?

**Update:** for the following code contributed by @dvantwisk, it works for `year2022week01st`, but not suitable to other elements:

```
s <- c('week 01st', 'weeks 02nd', 'year2022week01st', 'week 4th')
gsub('(year[0-9]{4,})(week)(0{0,})([1-9]{1})([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,})', '\\1\\2\\4\\5', s)
```

Out:

```
[1] "week 01st"       "weeks 02nd"      "year2022week1st" "week 4th"
```

Comment: And if you replace the `^` with space?

Comment: fyi the `^` matches at the _beginning_ of a string

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity of my question, I updated a new `s`, if I only want to sub two digits numbers leading zero, then the problem I met is how could I sub 01, 02, 03, etc. to 1, 2, 3, etc. but avoid replace 2022 to 222?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
weeks?\h*\K0+(?=[1-9]\d*[a-zA-Z])
```

The pattern matches:

- `weeks?` Match week with optional s
- `\h*\K` Match optional spaces and forget what is matched so far
- `0+` Match 1+ times a zero
- `(?=[1-9]\d*[a-zA-Z])` Positive lookahead, assert a char 1-9, optional digit and a char a-zA-Z to the right

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lg23Vh/1) and a [R demo](https://ideone.com/VVaax4).

In the replacement use an empty string.

For example

```
s <- c('week 01st', 'weeks 02nd', 'year2022week01st', 'week 4th')
gsub("weeks?\\h*\\K0+(?=[1-9]\\d*[a-zA-Z])", '', s, perl=T)
```

Output

```
[1] "week 1st"        "weeks 2nd"       "year2022week1st" "week 4th"
```

---

Or with 2 capture groups:

```
(weeks?\h*)0+([1-9]\d*[a-zA-Z])
```

Example:

```
s <- c('week 01st', 'weeks 02nd', 'year2022week01st', 'week 4th')
gsub("(weeks?\\h*)0+([1-9]\\d*[a-zA-Z])", '\\1\\2', s,)
```

Output

```
[1] "week 01st"       "weeks 02nd"      "year2022week1st" "week 4th"
```

Comment: many thanks, just FYI, `s <- c('week 01st', 'weeks 02nd', 'year2022week01st', 'week 4th')` is for testing, not `c('week 1st', 'weeks 2nd', 'year2022week1st', 'week 4th')`. :)

Comment: @ahbon Ah I see, I copied the wrong line. It is updated now, it gives the same result :-)

Comment: Since you solution is more general to all cases, I accept yours, thanks to @dvantwisk for his help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`gsub('(week )(0{0,})([1-9]{1})([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,})', '\\1\\3\\4', week_string)`

`gsub()` takes three arguments as input: a pattern, a replacement, and a query character vector. Our strategy is to create a regular expression with four groups with `()`s.

We fist match 'week '.

We then match zero or more zeros with the expression `(0{0,})`. The first zero indicates the character we are trying to match and the expression `{0,}` indicates we are trying to match zero (hence the 0) or more (hence the comma) times.

Our third group is matching any number between 1 to 9 one time.

Out fourth group is to match any number between 0 to 9 or any letter 1 or more times

Our replacement is `'\\1\\3\\4'`. This indicates we only want to keep group one and three in our result. Thus the output is:

`[1] "week 1st" "week 2nd" "week 3rd" "week 4th"`

Comment: Could u please test `s <- 'year2022week01st'`, how could I get an output string: `year2022week1st`?

Comment: How could I sub `01, 02, 03, etc.` to `1, 2, 3, etc.` but avoid replace `2022` to `222`?

Comment: `gsub('(year[0-9]{4,})(week)(0{0,})([1-9]{1})([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,})', '\\1\\2\\4\\5', s)` Just add more groups into your pattern.

Comment: Thanks your last code works for `s <- 'year2022week01st'`, it seems no general solution to this issue so far.

Comment: For what it's worth, regular expressions that do a particular thing can often be complex. It's likely the case that there's not a simple solution.

Comment: To simplify, if I want to convert `s <- c('01 blablabla the 01 week blablabla', 'blabla the 02 week blablabla')` to `c('01 blablabla the 1 week blablabla', 'blabla the 2 week blablabla')`, which means I will only sub numbers between `the` and `week`, how could I modify ur code?

Comment: I get it, we should use `gsub('(the )(0{0,})([1-9]{1})( week)', '\\1\\3\\4', s)`, right?